# crawling mutiple websites concurrently in single program

Tags: java

1.how to crawl more than 2 sites at a same time in single program
2.How to get in inUrl in implemented class of Runnabkle

1.List inUrl=new ArrayList();

```
    System.out.println("Numof url");
    final int urlSize=scanner.nextInt();
    int count =0;
    while (count < urlSize) {
        System.out.println("Enter Name of url");
    inUrl.add(scanner.next());
        count++;
    }

  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MYTHREADS);

  for (int i = 0; i < inUrl.size(); i++) {
    //System.out.println();
      System.out.println(inUrl.get(i));
      Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(inUrl.get(i));
        executor.execute(worker);
        executor.shutdown();
    2.public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public String inUrl;
   int s;
    int urlSize=s;
 List<String> Url;
  public  MyRunnable(String inUrl) {
        this.inUrl = inUrl;
    }
  3.how to repeat  the crawling for Multiplesites in run method
```